# Passing <<value to macro

Tags: c++, visual-c++, metaprogramming

I would like to make macro which could handle stream passed to it. How to handle "hello" in macro body passed passed by "<<"

```
#define MY_MACRO(){std::cout<<value;}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    MY_MACRO<<"hello";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: macros work with substitution.. if you do a substitution, you'll see that your example doesn't make sense.

Comment: What do you mean by handle. What do you want to achieve with the macro?

Comment: You cannot. On top of that, macros should not be used to generate code (what you are doing is bad practice). Consider defining a class instead, and define the operators as you need them.

Answer (score 1):

A macro does a text substitution.  If we expand it your source becomes:

```
{std::cout<<value;}<<"hello";
```

Which is not going to work.

Now you can rewrite your macro to:

```
#define OUTPUT(x) std::cout << x
```

And you would use it like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define OUTPUT(x) std::cout << x

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{ 
    OUTPUT("test");
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d960aee7d49049d5)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You seem to confuse macros and functions.  Macros are something completely different from functions; they do textual replacement in a preprocessor, before the actual compiler even sees to code.  Let me fix your example slightly (I'll explain below):

```
#define MY_MACRO {std::cout<<value;}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    MY_MACRO<<"hello";

    return 0;
}
```

The preprocessor then genrates something like this:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    {std::cout<<value;}<<"hello";

    return 0;
}
```

Which is obviously bogus.

What you probably meant was either

1. Some prefix which is contained in some static variable `value` which should be output *each time* you use `MY_MACRO`.  Then you want

   ```
   #define MY_MACRO (std::cout<<value)

   int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
   {
       MY_MACRO<<"hello";

       return 0;
   }
   ```

   **Note1:** The space after `MY_MACRO` is important.

   **Note2:** It will often work without the parens around `(std::cout<<value)`, but you should include them to be on the safe side.  That will most likely save you some headache later.
2. You want to give an argument to `MY_MACRO`, and it should be possible to specify complex constructs there (e.g. `MY_MACRO("The answer is " << 42)`).  Then you want to use something like

   ```
   #define MY_MACRO(value) (std::cout<<value)

   int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
   {
       MY_MACRO("hello");

       return 0;
   }
   ```

   **Note3:** Often it is advised to put parans around the macro parameters, and usually that is a good idea.  Not in this case however, because then `MY_MACRO("The answer is " << 42);` would expand to `(std::cout << ("The answer is " << 42));`, which would try to shift a character pointer left by 42 bits before piping it into `std::cout`.

Now to get back to the first little fix I mentioned.  Originally you defined a function-style macro `#define MY_MACRO()...`.  This will only be replaced by the preprocessor if it appears in the program text followed by an opening paren `(`, like so: `MY_MACRO()<<"hello";`.  I removed the emtpy pair of parens in the macro definition, making it an object-style macro.  If you try to define an object-style macro with a replacement text that starts with an opening paren `(`, you have to seperate the macro name and the paren by whitespace to disambiguate it from a function-style macro definition.  That's what **Note1** was about.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do such thing. You can do this only with operator overloading. Of course you can do

```
#define MY_MACRO std::cout
```

but it's not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at glog (Google log), it allows logging like:

```
LOG(INFO) << "Found " << num_cookies << " cookies";
```

https://github.com/google/glog